# Azure AD Get Members using Logic apps

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

I want to get all group members in the Azure AD group. 5000 users are there. I'm only getting the 500 users using the Azure AD connector Get group members how can I do it in loop so that it will move to 101 to 200 users like that all the way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit more involved, but what you need to do is to get the raw response, azure ad connector is essentially a graph api call, so when you call that, it'll get some max amount of users, but also in the response, there will be a url in the @odata.nextLink field. this field contains the url to the next page of results. so in logic app or flow, you will have to first have a return list variable, create a loop that checks if the value of that while odata.nextlink is not null. then keep iterating and adding the results to the return list variable . until you reach the end, then return the return list variable.

Comment: In the settings I saw pagination turned off I turned on and set the threshold to high it worked